# how to test wagtail admin pages using the django test client?

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to write some tests using the Django Test Client to check on my customisations of the wagtail admin.  I've tried:

```
self.user = get_user_model().objects.create(
    username='addy', is_staff=True
)
self.client.force_login(self.user)
response = self.client.get(f'/admin/pages/{self.thing.id}/edit/')
```

But I still end up seeing an `HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/admin/login/?next=/admin/pages/6/edit/">`

Am I missing some crucial attribute to the user that Wagtail wants in ordet to let them view wagtail-admin pages?

Answer (score 2):

Wagtail doesn't use the `is_staff` flag to determine access to the admin - you need to assign your user the `wagtailadmin.access_admin` permission instead.

See https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c6666c6de5e83bf94d18324858c121e6584ba47d/wagtail/wagtailsites/tests.py#L258 for an example of setting up a test user with the right permissions.

Comment: a definite improvement!  I'm now getting a 403 instead of a 302.  still not quite right tho.  have even tried `user_permissions.add(*Permission.objects.all())`

Comment: To give your user access to /admin/pages/<id>/edit/, you'll need to set up GroupPagePermission records: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/14a36f29c0e20a992a57f965b5757567ffe1e796/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L1594 . Alternatively, make them a superuser by setting is_admin=True.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in the end:

```
self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_superuser(
    username='addy', email='admin@example.com', password='passwood321'
)
```

Just setting `is_staff` wasn't enough.  With due thanks to @gasman above, users don't have an `is_admin` atttribute.  they do have `is_superuser`, so this code works just as well (and is probably better since it doesn't need an irrelevant email or password):

```
self.user = get_user_model().objects.create(username='addy', is_superuser=True)
self.client.force_login(self.user)
```